# Programatically Post a URL on a Facebook Group

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am trying to automate article seeding on facebook groups,however I am unable to find relevant APIs to do it.Is it possible to post an article(which includes all OG tags) on a Facebook group using any of its APIs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `/group-id/feed` endpoint to post to a group:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/group/feed#publish

A better alternative would be the Share Dialog:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog

Autoposting and prefilling the message is not allowed, so it´s better to just use the Share Dialog. No user authorization required and it takes the OG tags from the URL.